# c++ vector iterator deference inconsistency

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have the following code. When dereference in line 5, I got wrong value of `(*it)->sec`. while in line 8, I can obtain correct value. The only difference I noticed is one is inside the for loop, the other is outside the for loop. Is there some subtle point I missing here.  I basically want to obtain the member value of the first element in the vector. What's the correct way of obtaining the first `(*it)->sec` before(outside) the for loop?

```
void print_allAddresses(std::vector<EntryObj *> EntryObj_vec){
    std::cout << "time(sec:microsec) dataType memoryValue" << std::endl;
    std::vector<EntryObj *>::iterator it;
    it = EntryObj_vec.begin();
    std::cout << (*it)->sec << std::endl; //EntryObj_vec.front()->sec also wrong here.
    for(it = EntryObj_vec.begin(); it != EntryObj_vec.end(); ++it){
        if(!(*it)->parameters.empty()){
            std::cout << (*it)->sec << "." << (*it)->microsecond << " "; 

            std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it_map;
            for (it_map = (*it)->parameters.begin(); it_map != (*it)->parameters.end(); it_map++){
                std::cout << "(" << it_map->first<< ")" << " " << it_map->second << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Add `assert(!EntryObj_vec.empty())` at the start of the function. I'd guess you'll find that you call the function with an empty vector and accessing the first element of an empty vector is undefined behavior.

Comment: You probably want to do a pass by reference here, passing a vector by copy can get quite expensive.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I tested. The vector is not empty.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks for the reminder. It didn't fix the problem. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: What do you mean "wrong value of sec"?  It works fine in my testing... see [here](http://ideone.com/dSXMgk).  If you have a problem, try to fork and modify the ideone.com code until you have a minimal complete program you can post here illustrating the problem.  (Your actual problem might be quite different - e.g. populating the vector with pointers that are no longer valid, perhaps because they're to locals that left scope, or `new`-ed objects prematurely `delete`-d...?)

Comment: @TonyD, I have the value 47009156, the first (*it)->sec outside for loop give me a huge value 140085589379080.

Comment: @Harry: OK. It seems the first entry is still funny. Possibly `(*it)->parameters.empty()` is `true` instead which would cause the loop to skip its output. Since you only gave some small excerpt of your code lacking any declarations and a vague description of what the problem is there is quite a bit of guesswork needed...

Comment: @Harry: unless you show us the code that prints 47009156 before calling `print_allAddresses` we can't comment on the truth of your impression.  Clearly the code doesn't do what you expect, so there's a gap in your understanding and telling us what you think's true isn't useful.  Crop the code down to the minimum amount that reproduces the problem and post it.  Failing that, I for one will be voting to close the problem as unreproducible with posted code....

Comment: @Harry I didn't expect it to fix the problem, sorry if I misled you.

Comment: @DietmarKühlAs always, I made a dumb mistake. You hit the point. The first few element was not construct correctly. In the loop, they are skipped by the if conditional check. Any way, thank you TonyD,for your time. I now can proceed with my project.